# SQL Group By Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by

I have three tables I need to join in order to tell what documents a product needs.  Not all documents are needed on each product.

There is a Document table, a Product table, and a DocTracking table that tracks the documents associated with products

```
Product Table
ProdID   ProdName
1        Ball
2        Wheel
```

```
DocTracking Table
ProdID     DocID
1          1
1          2
2          2
```

I want the join to look like this:

```
ProdID     ProdName   Needs Word Doc?    Needs Excel Doc?
1          Ball       Yes                Yes
2          Wheel      No                 Yes
```

Any help would be appreciated, if I need to make this into a Stored Procedure, that is fine.

Comment: Search for "pivot table" here on SO.  You can also do it with Case statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only those documents and they are fix you can use this query:

```
SELECT ProdID, ProdName,      
       [Needs Word Doc] = CASE WHEN EXISTS(
           SELECT 1 FROM Document  d INNER JOIN DocTracking dt ON d.DocID=dt.DocID
           WHERE dt.ProdID = p.ProdID AND d.[Doc Name] = 'Word Document'
       ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END,
       [Needs Excel Doc] = CASE WHEN EXISTS(
           SELECT 1 FROM Document  d INNER JOIN DocTracking dt ON d.DocID=dt.DocID
           WHERE dt.ProdID = p.ProdID AND d.[Doc Name] = ' Excel Spreadsheet'
       ) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
FROM dbo.Product  p
```

Of course you could also use the `DocID`, then the query doesn't depend on the name.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Unfortunately, there are about 20 documents in "real life," and it is not fixed, there could be more down the road.

Comment: I'm just going to go with this for now, but if someone has a better way, let me know.  I've heard not to use cursors, but seems like a time to use it?

Answer (score 1):

```
select P.ProdID, P.ProdName, 
       case 
          when DW.DocID is null then 'Yes'
          else 'No' 
       end as NeedsWordDoc,    
       case 
          when DE.DocID is null then 'Yes'
          else 'No' 
       end as NeedsExcelDoc
from Product P
left join DocTracking DTW on DTW.ProdId = P.ProdId
left join Document DW on DW.DocID = DTW.DocID
                          and DW.Name = 'Word Document'
left join DocTracking DTE on DTE.ProdId = P.ProdId
left join Document DE on DE.DocID = DTE.DocID
                          and DE.Name = 'Excel Spreadsheet'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a little more complicated than a typical pivot query.  But, the only challenging part is determining which documents are included, and then getting `'Yes'` or `'No'` out.

The following does this with `coalesce()` and a conditional that checks for the presence of one type of document:

```
select pt.ProdId, pt.ProdName,
       coalesce(MAX(case when dt.DocId = 1 then 'Yes' end), 'No') as "Needs Word Doc?",
       coalesce(MAX(case when dt.DocId = 2 then 'Yes' end), 'No') as "Needs Excel Doc?"
from ProductTable pt left outer join
     DocTracking dt 
     on dt.ProdId = dt.ProdId
group by pt.ProdId, pt.ProdName;
```

Note that SQL queries return a fixed number of columns.  So, you cannot have a SQL query that simply returns a different number of columns based on what is present in the documents table.  You can *create* a SQL query in a string and then use a database-specific command to run it.

Answer (score 0):

may be this would help you - using pivot:

```
select ProdId, ProdName, 
case when isnull([Word Document],0)<>0 then 'Yes'
else 'No' 
end as  [Needs Word Doc?],
case when isnull([Excel Spreadsheet],0)<>0 then 'Yes'
else 'No' 
end as  [Needs Excel Spreadsheet?]
 from
(
select p.ProdId,p.ProdName,d.DocId,d.DocName from 
@Prod p left join 
@Track t
on p.ProdId=t.ProdId 
inner join @Doc d
on t.DocId=d.DocId
)
as temp
pivot
(max(DocID)
For DocName in ([Word Document],[Excel Spreadsheet])
)
as pvt
```